# Access to UITransitionView's From UIWindow

Tags: swift, uiwindow, rootviewcontroller, view-hierarchy

In my application I have a UINavigationController, After authentication I run perform segue(Push replace) for navigating to UINavigationController, when app goes to background I present Authentication page again, I do this in a classed I named it ScreenLocker

```
 UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vcAuthentication
```

But after `n` time's app goes to background I have `n` UINavigationControllers and one Authentication controller (when I saw debug view hierarchy I found it), know for showing UINavigationController How can I remove Authentication view controller?

[image]

[image]

**My current view controller is highlighted view controller, it's in front of all views, I want to remove it and showing another views.**

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code how you are initializing the navigation controller?

Comment: performSegue(withIdentifier: R.segue.authenticationViewController.authenticationToCardList.identifier, sender: self)

Comment: I think it's because of changing root view controller, I mentioned it in my question

Comment: Rather using code, did u try it with storyboard? Try it with storyboard and let me know if the problem is still there?

Comment: You are changing the rootviewcontroller in appdelegate only right?

Comment: Changing view controller depend on many things, I can't handle it in storyboard.

Comment: No I changed it on another class, I have a class I named it screen locker, it's time base, after 1 minutes I lock app automatically

Comment: May be before that class you have to make the current navigationcontroller to nil.

Comment: This is happening because you are initializing the navigationcontroller in appdelegate as well as in screenlocker class, this what i understood?

Comment: I don't want to pass navigation controller to this class:-(

Comment: @Mr Hamed you need to provide the code what you are doing in appdelegate and in this class, i am not able to get the scenario what you are working on?

Comment: It seems there is a way to get all controllers in the app!! I'll find this

Comment: It seems to me, you playing with rootviewcontroller, which will overwrite the current rootviewcontroller everytime you did.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Updating the question with screenshot doesn't help unless, i don't see the code what you are doing beneath,see i have no idea how you are transitioning, how you are locking the screen, as you have mentioned you are changing the rootviewcontroller sometimes, so share the code so that we can help to remove your VCs which you don't want.

Comment: In the screenshot, i see many VCs overlapping each other.